# Find the null value inside dynamic array list and get the value of this parent

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My "spreads" have dynamic array number inside (different numbers per events). Each of the arrays have this `alt_line_id: null`. I want to get which array object does have this value null value and then display the "home & away" values to my html.

My example array:

```
"events": [
    "periods": {
        "num_0": {
            "line_id": 2250607026,
            "number": 0,
            "cutoff": "2023-09-18T23:15:00Z",
            "period_status": 1,
            "money_line": {
                "home": 2.5,
                "draw": null,
                "away": 1.598
            },
            "spreads": {
                "3.0": {
                    "hdp": 3.0,
                    "alt_line_id": null,
                    "home": 2.0,
                    "away": 1.909,
                    "max": 30000.0
                },
                "5.5": {
                    "hdp": 5.5,
                    "alt_line_id": 36582376056,
                    "home": 1.625,
                    "away": 2.39,
                    "max": 30000.0
                },
                "5.0": {
                    "hdp": 5.0,
                    "alt_line_id": 36582376059,
                    "home": 1.662,
                    "away": 2.32,
                    "max": 30000.0
                },
                "4.5": {
                    "hdp": 4.5,
                    "alt_line_id": 36582376062,
                    "home": 1.694,
                    "away": 2.26,
                    "max": 30000.0
                },
                "4.0": {
                    "hdp": 4.0,
                    "alt_line_id": 36582376064,
                    "home": 1.746,
                    "away": 2.19,
                    "max": 30000.0
                },
            },
        },
    },
]
```

In my array above, the "spreads" object have dynamic list of array and for example "3.0" is the one that have `"alt_line_id": null`. Once it found, I want to get the name of this object so that I can get the "home" & "away" by using calling it like this: `obj.events[i].periods.num_0.spreads['**my dynamic array here**'].home`

Here's my code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "odds.json", true);
xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.onload = function() {
    const obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var out = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.events.length; i++) {

        out += '<tr>'
                + '<td class="home_team">'+ obj.events[i].home +'</td>'
                + '<td class="home_moneyline">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.money_line.home +'</td>'
                + '<td class="home_spreads">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.spreads['my dynamic array here'].home +'</td>'
                + '<td class="home_totals">'+  +'</td>'
                + '<td class="home_totalgame">'
                    + '<div>Over <span class="htg_over">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.team_total.home.over +'</span></div>'
                    + '<div>Under <span class="htg_under">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.team_total.home.under +'</span></div>'
                + '</td>'
            + '</tr>'
            + '<tr>'
                + '<td class="away_team">'+ obj.events[i].away +'</td>'
                + '<td class="away_moneyline">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.money_line.away +'</td>'
                + '<td class="away_spreads">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.spreads['my dynamic array here'].away +'</td>'
                + '<td class="away_totals">'+  +'</td>'
                + '<td class="away_totalgame">'
                    + '<div>Over <span class="atg_over">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.team_total.away.over +'</span></div>'
                    + '<div>Under <span class="atg_under">'+ obj.events[i].periods.num_0.team_total.away.under +'</span></div>'
                + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById("odds-list").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: `const savethistovariable = Object.values(obj.events[i].periods.num_0.spreads).find(x => x.alt_line_id === null)` and then you can `savethistovariable.home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 0; i < obj.events.length; i++) {
  const spreads = obj.events[i].periods.num_0.spreads;
  const spreadKeys = Object.keys(spreads);
  const nullSpreadKey = spreadKeys.find(key => spreads[key].alt_line_id === null);
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you and it worked! i never know `Object.keys()` & I'm new to JavaScript.